# How sum specific array values with input onChange

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, onchange

I'm have a list of objects

```
{id: 182, symbol: 'ETHUSDT', recommended_to_buy_qty: '42.83213', current_qty_in_portfolio: '8.06928'}
{id: 183, symbol: 'XRPUSDT', recommended_to_buy_qty: '83.47332', current_qty_in_portfolio: '8.79834'}
{id: 184, symbol: 'ADAUSDT', recommended_to_buy_qty: '50.72704', current_qty_in_portfolio: '3.79095'}
```

I need to sum two values in array with onChange input

On every change values is summed

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0)

    function handleChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
}
```

I'm create input form and it's works but change all my mapped values at once

```
<Form.Control onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />
```

How can i change only one item in array at once on every onChange event?

Comment: Can you share your mapping code? Are you mapping over the first list of objects?

Comment: Your `handleChange()` doesn't do any summing, where is that logic?

Comment: summing looks like this for now

`
{(Number(inputValue) + Number(recommendationInit.data.recommended_positions[index].current_qty_in_portfolio)).toFixed(5)}
`

 but it's working

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74834173/edit) and add more detail, it is unclear what you are asking and what you are currently doing. What does you function to `sum` values look like? Which property of your object list are you trying to manipulate?

Comment: It's looks like this
[https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-booth-kcmecn?file=/src/App.js]
but request is from backend and for some reason in codesandbox fake data doesn't want to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `inputValue` store an object. The object can hold each objects `id` as its key and its associated sum. When mapping over your list, use the id of the current object your iterated on to obtain the value from `inputValue`. Within your `onChange`, you can pass the current objects `id` so that you can update it when you set your object state, eg:

```js
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({});

function handleChange(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setInputValue(obj => ({...obj, [id]: e.target.value}));
}
```

Now when you acceess your value, access it via the `id` of the current object. Below I'm using `?? 0` to use the value of `0` if `inputValue[el.id]` is `undefined` due to `el.id` not being set:

```
<Form.Control onChange={e => handleChange(e, el.id)} value={inputValue[el.id] ?? 0} />
```